# How to select or copy all text in InDesign document

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, indesign-scripting, javascript

I want to select all text content of every page in an InDesign document or copying all text in InDesign document. I have tried scripting method, but did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Utilities → Scripts → Javascript → Export All Stories`, right click, hit Run, choose Text or RTF, hit OK.

[image]

Comment: No sir, I want to select all pages or copy all pages